# Automatically downloading all files to a user preferred location on the machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, download

In my web application the client receives a set of file urls as json from the server. On the client side i then need to automatically download all the files and save them to a user preferred location.
Is there a way to do this using javascript or jquery ?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It would be a huge security breach if any website could download any files on your computer. You just can redirect the user to the different file locations, and he will have to select manually where he want to save them.

You can also create an archive on the server-side with a script language (php, sh...) and send this archive so the user need to download one file only, however he will have to unzip the archive on his computer.

Comment: Can i ask the user for a location to download files,just like we have a file input dialog ?

Comment: Well, the user browser will pop-up with his own configuration (oftenly the last file saved location), i don't think you can overload this behavior with javascript. But you can probably create a java applet to do so, however the user will need to approve your application before the download to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.I would use the second option you suggested where i create an archive on server.How can i delete this archive automatically after client download is complete ? . My server side code is in python as im using the django web framework.

Comment: You can create a cron task to clean-up old archives (1 day old, or so). Or clean the old archives when you create the new one (this could be very long for one client per day). Or a script who will create the archive, send the correct download headers to the client, print the whole file before deleting it. (but i don't recommand this method because it will take a long time of execution but the archive won't last after the script is called, if you don't have sufficient disk space, it's probably the best.)

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you will *never* be able to do that.